# MPI coordination of jobs and writing to files

Tags: concurrency, multiprocessing, mpi, openmpi

I've just started using OpenMPI with python. I'm running the same task with different inputs (like 300 of them) a few hundred times each. The results are independent of each other and each process prints its final answer to a file, so there really is no need for processes to communicate with each other. However, starting a new iteration requires all processes from the previous one being complete.

I have two questions. The first is easy enough, and I think the answer is yes, but if anyone can give me pointers in what to read that would be nice. When writing to a file, processes won't conflict, right? (is there a built in lock mechanism?)

My other questions is, what if one of the processes is taking too long to complete (too long in comparison to the other processes that were doing the same task, so maybe 2 or 3 times as long) and because of a few, the continuing execution of the program is being held back? Is there some way that I can keep track of how long a process has been running and if it goes past a specific time limit, can I terminate it?

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would be very thankful.

Comment: You're using MPI.  I understand what MPI is.  Now where do threads come into it?  A little code sample might help, or at least describe how your threading use is integrated with your MPI use.

Comment: @JohnZwinck probably the wrong word, maybe change all threads to processes instead? what I mean is each of the concurrent executions of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot here so I'm going to quote some parts of your question and go one step at a time.

> I'm running the same task with different inputs (like 300 of them) a few hundred times each.

If you can, it would be much more efficient to launch N processes just once, and give each of them M inputs at the start.  Don't launch N processes M times.

> The results are independent of each other and each process prints its final answer to a file, so there really is no need for processes to communicate with each other.

Then maybe you have no use for MPI, actually.  The whole point is to communicate, so if you aren't doing that it's totally unnecessary.

> However, starting a new iteration requires all processes from the previous one being complete.

Oh, well that's communication isn't it?  So in other words your pattern is:

**N jobs process N inputs, waiting for all to complete, and this is repeated M times.**

But presumably each input for each of the M iterations depends on the previous one, since you said the previous iteration must complete before starting the next.  So that's more communication!  So your pattern is:

**N jobs process N inputs, waiting for all to complete, then the next set of N inputs are computed, and this is repeated M times.**

> When writing to a file, processes won't conflict, right? (is there a built in lock mechanism?)

Right.  If two processes write to separate regions of the same file, there is no conflict.  There may be a performance penalty but this only matters if you write a lot.  You could also open the file in "append" mode, in which case any single write up to some kilobytes would be atomic, which might also work for some use cases.  If you need to write a lot of data, you're better off writing a separate file from each process.

> What if one of the processes is taking too long to complete (too long in comparison to the other processes that were doing the same task, so maybe 2 or 3 times as long) and because of a few, the continuing execution of the program is being held back? Is there some way that I can keep track of how long a process has been running and if it goes past a specific time limit, can I terminate it?

You should not do this, because the same input will just be processed slowly by another process later.  Unless you think there may be something wrong with the input, in which case each process should keep its own internal timer and give up if it exceeds a predetermined limit.

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I needed. One more question though, is there already an internal clock in each process we can access or is this something that needs to be implemented? If 'too long' is determined by the other processes running (so it would be the process with rank 0 that keeps track of this value?) can I kill a specific thread from another?

Comment: @rdm11: I figured you'd just use a standard timer like you'd use without MPI, in each individual process.  If you need more help with this you should post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

When writing to a file, there can be (often is) some coordination or serialization, but not at the application level.   These kernel-level implicit locks are not somtehing the application can request, but can have a big impact on performance.

Consider this scenario

"A writes 500 bytes at offset 0.  B writes 500 bytes at offset 1000"

These writes could happen concurrently -- but a lot depends on the underlying file system.  GPFS and Lustre have locking protocols that operate on blocks (GPFS) or pages (Lustre).  Both A and B will try to obtain a lock.  One will succeeed and proceed immediately and the other will proceed only after A has finished.